# How to fix onlyoffice some documert lost header and footer

Tags: onlyoffice

There is a document that have footer and header! when i use onlyoffice preview it、this document footer and header lost and Typesetting（Line spacing is compressed） is different from office navite software！ Someone knows how to solve it？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Someone knows how to solve it？
>
> There is a document

Could you please send your file to support@onlyoffice.com

Feel free to post it here (if it doesn't contain any sensitive information)

Comment: Thank you for your answer！Our company is very strict with information management, I will try to communicate with leaders and send documents to your mailbox！thank you for your support！

Comment: hello ibnpetr！The mail has been sent.

Comment: Sorry we weren't able to locate your message.
Could you please resend it with "stackoverflow" in the subject.

Comment: OK、I resent an email with the subject "send again(stackoverflow)"

Comment: No lack, please resend the file from your personal email.
Or create a new ticket at helpdesk.onlyoffice.com